# iOS Custom MKAnnotation object resembling MKUserLocation animation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I want to drop `MKAnnotationView` pins on a map and have the pins be animated much like the `MKUserLocation` animates (the blue dot with circular waves coming out)

How do you achieve this type of animation? What steps do I need to take?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Animate it like any UIView!

subclass MKAnnotationView for custom content. **don't go via repeated addAnnotation calls to animate it! that is wrong**

you can treat the anotationView just like any other view..

here is some code that has a blinking animation of images -- this code should get you started.

(not pretty but the exact stuff you will need for your case!)

```
#import "DDViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface DummyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>
@end
@implementation DummyAnnotation
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate { return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51, 10); }
- (NSString *)title { return @"Dummy"; }
@end

@interface DummyAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView
@end
@implementation DummyAnnotationView
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    imageView.animationImages = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.gif"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.gif"]];
    imageView.animationDuration = 5;
    [imageView startAnimating];
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    
    return self;
}
@end

@interface DDViewController() <MKMapViewDelegate>
@end
@implementation DDViewController

- (MKMapView*)mapView {
    return (MKMapView*)self.view;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    //init a region
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(51.0, 10.0), MKCoordinateSpanMake(2.0, 2.0));
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];

    //add a dumy pin
    DummyAnnotation *ann = [[DummyAnnotation alloc] init];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[DummyAnnotation class]]) {
        DummyAnnotationView *view = (id)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"animated"];
        if(!view)
            view =[[DummyAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"animated"];
        view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 59, 59);
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
        
        //
        //Animate it like any UIView!
            //
            
        CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
    
        //within the animation we will adjust the "opacity"
        //value of the layer
        theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];             
            //animation lasts 0.4 seconds
        theAnimation.duration=0.4;
        //and it repeats forever
        theAnimation.repeatCount= HUGE_VALF;
        //we want a reverse animation
        theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
        //justify the opacity as you like (1=fully visible, 0=unvisible)
        theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
        theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1];
            
        //Assign the animation to your UIImage layer and the 
        //animation will start immediately
        [view.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];
        
        return view;
    }
    return nil;
}

//---

@end
```

uploaded the working sample to my dropbox (it will go away eventually but the code above is all but the image resources and the default boilerplate code of an iOS app) :: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3753090/test.zip

Comment: @valeriy edited to be broken as I see it... why did you remove the braces after the if(!view) causing the adding of the animation to happen x times?

Comment: Your code leaves dequeued annotation initialised with stale data. This code works just fine if you have one annotation. But if you have several annotations of same type, you will come into trouble when you will scroll map and some annotations will disappear from map and new will appear. Those which appear will be dequeued and reused. But you are not initialising them with fresh data but leave them as is. Do you understand me? Your code will work just fine. But try change it so your annotation size gets scaled to real map size. Your approach will stop to work when your map is rescaled.

Comment: Here https://github.com/valeriyvan/MissingYandexLocatorAPIiOSExample is example project. ViewController.m uses some of your code. Try to return back removed braces and you will see how strange annotation's behaviour gets when you rescale and reposition map.

Comment: FYI, you correctly check `if (!view) { ... }` to instantiate an annotation view if one was not found, but if an annotation view was successfully dequeued, make sure to update the `annotation` property to be the annotation that was supplied to `viewForAnnotation`. This existing code, as it stands, may have the dequeued annotation failing to use the new `annotation`. This is a problem that only manifests itself appears if you have multiple annotations and you successfully dequeue one.

Comment: Don't get it. I check the isKindOfClass of the annotation. I guess I only miss view.annotation = annotation!?